# Highlight Active Cell in Excel Without Resetting Existing Filled Cells

Tags: vba, excel

How can I automatically highlight the entire row where an active cell is highlighted without getting rid of other cells that are highlighted? (I want to highlight the entire row when there is an active cell and then un-highlight it when I move away.) t

I know the following VBA code does that but it eliminates all other cells filled with color.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    ' Clear the color of all the cells
    Cells.Interior.ColorIndex = 0
    With Target
        ' Highlight the entire row and column that contain the active cell
        .EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = 8
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do that with `Conditional Formatting` and simple `VBA Event`. Follow these steps:

**In Excel:**

1. select range when you want to have highlighted rows... A1:J20 in this example

2. goto menu >> home >> conditional formatting >> new rule... >> use a formula to determine which cells to format

3. in formula textbox write this formula: `=CELL("row") = ROW(A1)`

4. set formatting stale by pressing 'format...' button

5. press ok

**In VBA**
in module of the sheet for which you made the above action use this event:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Target.Calculate
End Sub
```

Comment: This is much better than the one I posted above! At least here we don't have to rerun the macro every time.

Comment: Just have to make sure that the cell in ROW() corresponds to the first cell in the range you want to implement.

Comment: =CELL("col")=COLUMN(A1) when you want to highlight column as well.